# Simplifying polygons

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I want to turn digitized polygons into simpler shapes.

More precisely, given a noisy closed polyline, I want to fit a polygon to it with an imposed number of sides, such as a triangle or quadrilateral, assuming that the data can roughly match. The fitted polygons need not be inscribed  and/or circumscribed, an average fit is preferred. The number of polyline vertices will range between a few tenths and a few hundredths, and the polygons can be up to octagons. Robustness if preferred over accuracy. If that helps, the polygons can be assumed convex.

[image]

There are a few variants of the problem:

- the number of sides is given, and there are no other constraints;
- the number of sides is given and there are constraints such as right angles or parallel sides;
- the number of sides isn't specified and some optimum should be found.

I am looking for resources on how to address these questions. I know the Douglas-Peucker line simplification process pretty well but I don't think it suffices here (because of the constraints).

Comment: If the only constraint is the number of sides, you could try generating the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull#Convex_hull_of_a_finite_point_set) and then removing the points at which the angle is closest to $180^{\circ}$ until you have the desired number of sides.

Comment: @Wouter: quite interesting. Do we even need to consider the convex hull ?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki: in the examples shown, I don't see any ambiguity of this kind. And in the first variants, n is given.

Comment: Sorry,I mistaked posting.

Comment: Is vector graphics what you find? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics

Comment: @TakahiroWaki: I am working on flat polygons.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the polyline point distances (squared) to the centroid, to determine the likely intended vertices? Followed by an iterative approach (using harmonic, string-like "forces" acting on the vertices) to find the shape fulfilling the rules best matching the original?

Comment: @NominalAnimal: not so far, as in my initial thinking the polygons could be non-convex. That's a good suggestion. Now the problem is restated as that of finding N best local maxima in a noisy signal.

Comment: The maxima are actually easily found for low vertex count; side minima are easily misinterpreted as concave vertices, so it is best to use it to only identify the outermost vertices in the polygon. A sliding rectangular window filter, window width depending on the number of samples and desired number of outer vertices, should be easy to implement, low memory use, fast, and find those maxima easily. It might even work for nonconvex polygons' outer vertices; haven't tested it myself.

Comment: @NominalAnimal False maxima can arise in the middle of an edge, with a distance to the center larger than the distance to a valid vertex. Maxima selection won't be that easy.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: is your sliding window in the $x,y$ or the $r,\theta$ domain ?

Comment: Maximum at the middle of an edge? I don't see how that's possible; those are the side minima I was talking about. The window is in the $r$, $\theta$ domain. I could whip up some example code, if you happen to have some example digitizer data.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: you can see on few maxima on my pictures. Small bump is enough.

Comment: Ah, right. Vertex detection does definitely become harder the larger the vertex angles become. At this point, I would definitely collect a good-sized dataset (maybe a hundred or so hand-drawn polygons) to examine, before going further with any specific method. (It is interesting enough that if I had a touchscreen, I'd do some testing myself.)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that noisy lines change  n-polygon.It is necessarily that given a value k, my solution is
$$ax+b≦f(x) ≦ax+d$$and$$d-b≦k. $$

then choose $f(x)=ax+(b+d)/2$.

$g(x),h(x),・・・$

Surround shape with$ f(x),g(x),・・・$are simplified shape.

expression of edge detection is

$f(x)=(I_r-I_l)/2(erf(x/√2σ)+1))+I_l$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection

Is vector graphics what you find? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics  or  http://www.graphicmania.net/how-to-simplify-complex-paths-in-illustrator-cs5/

Comment: This is valid for a single line. I need to segment the shape in several lines.

Comment: g(x),h(x)・・・ finally can make closed polygon.

Comment: Can you describe a complete procedure ? There's nothing I can do with these fragments of information.

Comment: I am afraid you don't get my question. I have polygons and I need to approximate them with polygons of fewer sides.